# Unable to call javascript function from c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to call a javascript function from C# while **post back** below is my code.
I am getting an error as the function is not defined.

Javascript:

```
    function postBackResponse(){ 
       alert("Success"); 

    }
```

C# Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (IsPostBack)
{
  PostBk();
}

}
public void PostBk(){

string displayTasks = "PostPer";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "TasksListString = '" + displayTasks + "'; postBackResponse();", true);

}
```

Comment: you are calling `Page_Load();` but the javascript function name is `postBackResponse()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "TasksListString = '" + displayTasks + "'; Page_Load();", true);
```

with

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "postBackResponse();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> the function is not defined.

As suggested in error, the function you suppose to call must be defined in your javascript.

Remove the code written in **PostBk()** method and replace it with below code :

```
public void PostBk()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "script", "postBackResponse()", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add following code in page load

**Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(FrmTableReservation))**